# How to install Chrome in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, unix

I am using ubuntu 15.10 64bit.

```
Click Download Chrome.
Choose either 32 bit .deb (for 32bit Ubuntu) or 64 bit .deb (for 64bit Ubuntu)
Click Accept and Install.
Download .deb file to a folder (Downloads is the default folder)
Open up your Downloads folder.
Double-click the .deb file you just downloaded.
This should launch Ubuntu Software Centre.
```

I am using these steps but I am getting error like this:

> Fails to download package files
>    Check your Internet connection.

```
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_12.10.2+14.10.20140922-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch
```

But my Internet is UP and working well.

Answer (score 1):

From the `.deb` file:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Use the command `sudo apt-get -f install` to fix the missing dependencies

Using the regular repo:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```